# Arrows with math

Tags: arrows

On the following code

```
\begin{figure}[htbp!]
   \begin{center}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,baseline,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt]
          \draw[thick,->] (-3.5,0) -- (4.5,0) node[anchor=north west] {$\mathbb{Z}$};
           \foreach \x in {-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4}
           \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Somma algebrica} \label{fig:somma algebrica} %\label va messo qui 
    \end{center}
 \end{figure}
```

I would like to add arrows like the image below

[image]

So that I can show how to do the sum of two ore more numbers, but I don't know how to integrate it in my code.

Thanks for your hints

Gian Carlo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3.14159mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 6mm,
            > = Straight Barb,
   arr/.style = {very thick, gray, shorten <=1pt,
                 -{Triangle[length=3pt]}, looseness=3}
                        ]
\draw[thick,->] (-3.5,0) -- (5,0) node[below left=2pt] {$\mathbb{Z}$};
\foreach \x in {-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4}
    \draw (\x,2pt) -- ++ (0,-4pt) node (n\x) [below] {$\x$};
\draw[arr]  (n1) to [out=270, in=270] (n0);
\draw[arr]  (n0) to [out=270, in=270] (n-1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```